# Motion Detection using MMA8451 accelerometer and Rpi, am I reading and writing the registers properly?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c

Goodmorning everybody,
I am trying to make a project with my raspberry pi 2b+ and the accelerometer MMA8451.
I want put the Rpi on a cart and measure the vibrations just if it is moving in the X direction.
Actually I'm just try to modify the Tony Dicola code adding the motion detection, here his code:
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_MMA8451

I have look the accelerometer datasheet https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MMA8451Q.pdf
and the specific Motion Detect chapter also http://cache.freescale.com/files/sensor ... AN4070.pdf
(and also lot of others datasheets..)
In this last one at page 12 there is an example, it is bit different from my target but I was following it for understand how it works..
It is write in C++, I have to converting it in python..
But I found a perfect explanation here:
https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/b447ac46dced47d6a94c811725f28b1b
it is really well done, it use a different device but the principle it's obvious the same I thoght.. but I am not able to understand how to implement easily the motion detection, I'm just follow the instructions but it didn't works, damn it.

I don't think it's a register configuration problem..
Anyone can tell me if in the Tony DiCola code something important is missing?
I'm new to python and i2c, probably it's not something difficult.

As #planet suggest:

In my main Routine I have:

```
import time
import board
import busio
import adafruit_mma8451V4
import csv
import datetime

# Initialize I2C bus.
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

# Initialize MMA8451 module.
sensor = adafruit_mma8451V4.MMA8451(i2c)
while True:
   while sensor.Motion():
       with open('Accelerometer.csv', 'a+') as csvfile:
           sensorwriter = csv.writer(csvfile) #, delimiter=' ',
                                   #quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
           sensorwriter.writerow(['Datetime', 'X_Accel (m/s^2)', 'Y_Accel (m/s^2)', 'Z_Accel (m/s^2)'])

            x, y, z = sensor.acceleration
            time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
            sensor.MotionRegister()    
            
            print('Time={0}   X={1:0.3f} m/s^2  Y:{2:0.3f} m/s^2  Z:{3:0.3f} m/s^2'.format(time_now, X, Y, Z))
            sensorwriter.writerow([time_now, X, Y, Z])
            time.sleep(2)
    IntSourceMFF = sensor.MotionRegister()
```

Pretty much rough I know..

This is my adding in the I2C class:

```
def Motion (self): #, IntSourceSystem,IntSourceMFF):
    print(_MMA8451_INT_SOURCE)
    print(_MMA8451_REG_CTRL_REG1)
    self._write_u8(_MMA8451_REG_CTRL_REG1, 0x18) # Standby Mode
    #self._write_u8(_MMA8451_REG_CTRL_REG1, 0x00)        # deactivate
    print(_MMA8451_REG_CTRL_REG1)
    self._write_u8(REG_FF_MT_CONFIG, 0xD8) #Moto detection X axe 
    self._write_u8(REG_FF_MT_THS, 0x30)    #threshold 1g: es 3g/0.063g = 48 counts = 30 (hexadecimal)
    self._write_u8(REG_FF_MT_COUNT, 0x0A) #Debounce counter, set at 100ms timer and 800Hz
    self._write_u8(_MMA8451_REG_CTRL_REG4, 0x04)
    self._write_u8(_MMA8451_REG_CTRL_REG5, 0x04)
    print(_MMA8451_INT_SOURCE)
    CTRLreg1 = self._read_u8(_MMA8451_REG_CTRL_REG1)
##  CTRLreg1 |= 0x01
##  self._write_u8(_MMA8451_REG_CTRL_REG1, CTRLreg1)
    self._write_u8(_MMA8451_REG_CTRL_REG1, CTRLreg1 | 0x01) #activated
    print(_MMA8451_REG_CTRL_REG1)
    #self._write_u8(CTRLreg1)
    #IntSourceSystem = self._read_u8(_MMA8451_INT_SOURCE)
    #self._read_into(_MMA8451_INT_SOURCE, self._BUFFER, count=6)
    #IntSourceSystem = struct.unpack('>hhh', self._BUFFER)        
    #IntSourceSystem = self._read_u8(0x0C)
    #print(IntSourceSystem)
    #print(IntSourceSystem & 0b100)
    #Int_SourceSystem = (IntSourceSystem & 0x04)
    #print(Int_SourceSystem)       
    #if ((IntSourceSystem & 0x04) == 0x04):
    #if ((IntSourceSystem & 0x04) >0):
    #if ((_MMA8451_INT_SOURCE & 0x04) == 0x04):
    #if ((self._read_u8(_MMA8451_INT_SOURCE) & 0x04) == 0x04):
    print(self._read_u8(_MMA8451_INT_SOURCE & 0x04))
    if self._read_u8(_MMA8451_INT_SOURCE & 0x04) > 0:
    #if ((self._read_u8(_MMA8451_INT_SOURCE) & 0b100) == 0b100):       
        print("You are into if")
        return True
    else:
        print("You are into else")
        return False

def MotionRegister (self):
    return self._read_u8(REG_MT_SRC)
```

I'm using the print for take a look into the register and looks like my actions aren't ever sufficient to make True the if condition into def Motion.
Is it a read/write problem? A standby/Activation problem?

In the comments there are some of the line of code I just tried (probably delete them it's a good idea..)

Here there are the registers:

```
    # Internal constants:
_MMA8451_DEFAULT_ADDRESS   = const(0x1D)
_MMA8451_REG_OUT_X_MSB     = const(0x01)
_MMA8451_REG_SYSMOD        = const(0x0B)
_MMA8451_REG_WHOAMI        = const(0x0D)
_MMA8451_REG_XYZ_DATA_CFG  = const(0x0E)
_MMA8451_REG_PL_STATUS     = const(0x10)
_MMA8451_REG_PL_CFG        = const(0x11)
_MMA8451_REG_CTRL_REG1     = const(0x2A)
_MMA8451_REG_CTRL_REG2     = const(0x2B)
_MMA8451_REG_CTRL_REG4     = const(0x2D)
_MMA8451_REG_CTRL_REG5     = const(0x2E)
_MMA8451_DATARATE_MASK     = const(0b111)
    
_MMA8451_INT_SOURCE        = const(0x0C)
    
#Register Setting for the Motion/Freefall Function
REG_FF_MT_CONFIG    = const(0x15)  # Motion/Freefall Configuration
REG_FF_MT_THS       = const(0x17)  # Setting the Treshold
REG_FF_MT_COUNT     = const(0x18)  # Setting the Debounce Counter
REG_MT_SRC          = const(0x16)  # Motion/Freefall Source Detection
```

My output (they are just the print) are:

```
12
42
42
12
42
0
You are into else
```

I'm thinking can be a read and write problem with the registers, in my code I have:

```
def _read_into(self, address, buf, count=None):
    # Read bytes from the specified address into the provided buffer.
    # If count is not specified (the default) the entire buffer is filled,
    # otherwise only count bytes are copied in.
    # It's silly that pylint complains about an explicit check that buf
    # has at least 1 value.  I don't trust the implicit true/false
    # recommendation as it was not designed for bytearrays which may not
    # follow that semantic.  Ignore pylint's superfulous complaint.
    assert len(buf) > 0  #pylint: disable=len-as-condition
    if count is None:
        count = len(buf)
    with self._device as i2c:
        i2c.write_then_readinto(bytes([address & 0xFF]), buf,
                                in_end=count, stop=False)

def _read_u8(self, address):
    # Read an 8-bit unsigned value from the specified 8-bit address.
    self._read_into(address, self._BUFFER, count=1)
    return self._BUFFER[0]

def _write_u8(self, address, val):
    # Write an 8-bit unsigned value to the specified 8-bit address.
    with self._device as i2c:
        self._BUFFER[0] = address & 0xFF
        self._BUFFER[1] = val & 0xFF
        i2c.write(self._BUFFER, end=2)
```

But in the explanation website that I have mentioned it use:

```
def _write_8(self, address, data):
    # Write 1 byte of data from the specified 16-bit register address.
    with self._device:
        self._device.write(bytes((address >> 8) & 0xFF,
                                   address & 0xFF,
                                   data))

def _write_16(self, address, data):
    # Write a 16-bit big endian value to the specified 16-bit register
    # address.
    with self._device:
        self._device.write(bytes((address >> 8) & 0xFF,
                                   address & 0xFF,
                                  (data >> 8) & 0xFF,
                                   data & 0xFF))

def _read_8(self, address):
    # Read and return a byte from the specified 16-bit register address.
    with self._device:
        self._device.write(bytes((address >> 8) & 0xFF,
                                   address & 0xFF),
                           stop=False)
        result = bytearray(1)
        self._device.read_into(result)
        return result0

def _read_16(self, address):
    # Read and return a 16-bit unsigned big endian value read from the
    # specified 16-bit register address.
    with self._device:
        self._device.write(bytes((address >> 8) & 0xFF,
                                   address & 0xFF),
                           stop=False)
        result = bytearray(2)
        self._device.read_into(result)
        return (result0 << 8) | result1
```

I don't think the 16 bit read and writing is useful for me, but the 8 bit function are different, is it the problem?
How can I handle it?
Sorry for the post too long, I hope it's all useful..

If it's not enough, in the image there is the instance from the datasheet that I'm following:

[Motion Detection Datasheet Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BC0vI.png)

Comment: Please incorporate the relevant parts from your links so that your question also remains understandable when the links are broken. And more importantly, please share what you actually tried (share *your* code and where the actual problem with that lies).

Comment: @planetmaker I have edited the post, I hope I followed the prassi